# Convert Queue To List

Tags: c#, list, queue

```
var queue = new Queue<ExchangeEmailInformation>(newMails);
```

How can I convert the above queue to `List`.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve? A queue is already an `IEnumerable<T>`... why would you have to convert it ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)

```
var list = queue.ToList();
```

Remember to include `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 5):

Since the [Queue<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) implements [IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) and the [List<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)  has a [constructor that accepts an IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx), you can simply pass the queue to that constructor:

```
var result = new List<ExchangeEmailInformation>(queue);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this... simple

System.Collections.Queue q = new System.Collections.Queue(4);
q.Enqueue("hai"); q.Enqueue("how"); q.Enqueue("are"); q.Enqueue("u");
int count = q.Count;
List<string> list = new List<string>();
for(int i =0; i < count; i++)
{
   list.Add(q.Dequeue().ToString());
}
```